# Filter a list based on number of columns of tables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a list of data frames like this:
[image]
I want to know how can I keep data frames with 15 columns and remove other data frames in this list in R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your future questions, please avoid screenshots and share an actual object using the `dput()` function.

You can use `purrr::keep()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
f=function(n) matrix(nrow=2, ncol=n) %>% as.data.frame()
x=list(
   df1=f(15),
   df2=f(15),
   df3=f(6),
   df4=f(6),
   df5=f(15)
)
x %>% keep(~ncol(.x)==15)
#> $df1
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15
#> 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 
#> $df2
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15
#> 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 
#> $df5
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15
#> 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

The second argument of `purrr::keep()` (first when piping) is a predicate function that should return a single logical value depending on whether the column should be kept or not.

Answer (score 2):

We may also do this with `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) ncol(x) == 15, out)
```

Or another option is `sapply` to get the number of columns and then create a logical vector to subset the `list`

```
out[sapply(out, ncol) == 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `ncol` is `length`. `length` gives the number of columns of a dataframe:

```
my_list[sapply(my_list, length)==15]
```